# Binding combox in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How to bind value with a `List<>` in `datagridview` in Windows application? I want that a user will select anything like he will select roll no from `combobox` in `datagridview` and on another cell will display the name of that roll no. Below I want Roll No will be combobox and name will be the `textbox` .

How will I do that?

```
  ===============================================================
   Roll No                Name
  ===============================================================
   509                John Watson
```